# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undifend

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am getting below error while executing the code.
**ERRORL:**

> uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

**CODE:**

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "/su/direct/dispatchorder",
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"shortFrom":shortFrom,"shortTo":shortTo},
      success: function(content){
        var obj = JSON.parse(content) 
        console.log(obj);
        var objects = obj.length
        var name = obj['name'];
        var qty = obj['qty'];
        for(i=0;i<=objects;i++)
        {
            document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=obj[i].name;
            document.getElementById('qty').innerHTML=obj[i].qty;
            console.log(obj[i]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: can you show `console.log(obj);`?

Comment: have json_encode the content from ajax file?